# Vim : nmap NERD-commenter command

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, nerdtree

I'm using [NERD-commenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter) on vim version 7.4.

I'd like to map `<F8>` to comment out multi lines with NERD-commenter 's command `\cc`.

I've checked that typing `\cc` is well working on blocked area.

The problem is that mapping `<F8>` to `\cc` is not working properly.

I've tried following lists in my *.vimrc* file.

```
nmap <F8> <leader>cc
nmap <F8> <Leader>cc
nmap <F8> <Plug>NERDComComment
...
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is any other plugin mapping to `<F8>`?  You can check by running `nmap <F8>`

Comment: @EvergreenTree No, there is no plugin mapping with `<F8>`. It is well working with other plugin (e.g. `nmap <F8> :NERDTree<CR>`)